Meaning of どうし with particle で
I have a small question which I couldn't look up anywhere else so I would like to summon the council of wise japolearners.
I'm translating a novel in order to learn and i came across this sentence.
「子供どうしで助けあうしかあるまいな」
The context is kids who are locked in a basement so basically from what I understand the meaning is easy to get, like “There is no other way than helping between each others kids” but I like to understand everything so there is this part in “子供どうしで” that I dont quite get because of どうしで.
Does it imply the meaning of “between” or something like that with the particle で?
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: 交わり合わないような項目同士 translation. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Adding more context might help. Who is saying this to whom in the novel? You can quote a larger potion of the text. If you give the title, people might be able to find a copy to read.
